# How to randomly assign values from one dictionary to another with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that does the following:

There will be 3 different courses to look ('Starter', 'Main', 'Desert'), and every team will be assigned to look one of these. Below actually assigns every team one course to cook, but not randomly.
the data list will be around **60 - 70 teams**, and I will check before the draw so that all teams are assigned to cook something as well as be invited as guests in the other 2 courses.
So at the end every team should look something and invite 2 other teams, and then they should be invited as guests for the other courses.

I haver updated the code and yes it is much better.
If i now want to invite two random teams from participants that has not had the course before, and have not met the other teams before. Do you have any suggestion how i should try to build this logic?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('C:\Peter\Programming\Projects\Cycling\participants.xlsx')
teams = data.to_dict(orient = 'index')
participants=list(teams)

starter = []
main = []
desert = []

starter = ['Starter'] * (len(participants)//3)
main = ['Main']*(len(participants)//3)
desert = ['Desert']*(len(participants)//3)

total_meals = starter + main + desert
random.shuffle(total_meals)
draw_meal = dict(zip(participants,total_meals))
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your excel file?

Comment: If any teams can taste any number of teams dish then I think you can assign the dishes arbitrarily given that at least one team is preparing starter, at least one team is preparing main and at least one team is preparing desert

Comment: Question is can i do the above in a better and easier way perhaps?

Comment: You are converting `pandas` to dict and doing the logic which is not required. You can process the data through pandas only. You are performing many unnecessary casting.

Comment: Also just notices you are changing a `list` when you are `iterating` over it. This can lead to problems.

Comment: If you provide sample data, it would be easier for people to help you :)

Comment: data = Teams,Player1,Player2,Address,Zip,City,Mail,Phone

Comment: example: {'Team1': {'Player1': 'Ola', 'Player2': 'Berit', 'Address': 'testv.1', 'Zip': 17531, 'City': 'Jonkoping', 'Mail': 'raman180@hotmail.com', 'Phone': 123456}, 'Team2': {'Player1': 'Bengt', 'Player2': 'Jane', 'Address': 'testv.2', 'Zip': 17531, 'City': 'Jonkoping', 'Mail': 'raman180@hotmail.com', 'Phone': 123456}

Answer (score 0):

First some improvements to your code:

```
starter = []
def add_starter():
    for team in range(len(participants)//3):
        x = 'Starter'
        starter.append(x)
```

Can be written as:

```
starter = ['Starter']*len(participants)//3
```

And when I understand your question correctly, then shuffling the `total_meals`list would do the trick:

```
random.shuffle(total_meals)
```

There is another nice way to create a dict from 2 lists by using `zip`:

```
draw_meal = dict(zip(participants,total_meals))
```

Comment: Yes, i think your solutions are much better, mine only gets longer and longer hehe. So if i now have who cooks what in place, what would be a good way to randomly pick 2 other teams to invite? (No team should have met before, and the team should not have had the course before.

Comment: If you dont mind using numpy then you can look into the `choice ` function which performs drawing with and without replacement with size=2. But actually this is out of the scope of the question.